# Do eggs have DHA? If yes, then how much on an average?

Tags: nutrition, egg

The egg nutrition website doesn't mention docosahexaenoic acid (DHA) in its list of egg ingredients:
http://www.eggnutritioncenter.org/egg-facts/nutrition-information-for-the-egg/

But, from: http://www.cholesterol-and-health.com/Egg_Yolk.html

> DHA and AA - 94 mg (yolk)

From: http://wholefoodcatalog.info/nutrient/docosahexaenoic_acid%28dha%29/eggs/

> 68 mg (per 18g edible portion) Hen's egg(yolk, raw)

Question: Do eggs have DHA? If yes, then how much on an average?

Comment: Depends on the size of the egg I would say...

Answer (score 2):

The content of DHA depends on food consumed by the hens.

Omega-3 or DHA eggs are from chickens that have been fed a diet supplemented by a source of omega-3 fatty acids as green algae , seaweed , flax and canola seeds
[Omega-3_fatty_acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega-3_fatty_acid)

[The study High-DHA eggs: feasibility as a means to enhance circulating DHA in mother and infant.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12848286)

mentions the difference between ordinary  (18 mg DHA/egg)
and  high-DHA hen eggs  (135 mg DHA/egg)

Comment: Is there a possibliity of eggs having 0 dha?

Comment: I can't find any credible source of information mentioning DHA free eggs. Some sources simply lack in declaration. Nevertheless I'd believe it would be possible to decrease the content by providing some special diet to the chicken.